# How to check for words that are not immediately followed by a keyword, how about words not surrounded by the keyword?

Tags: python, python-re, lookbehind

I am trying to look for words that do not immediately come before `the`.

Performed a positive look-behind to get the words that come after the keyword 'the' `(?<=the\W)`. However, I am unable to capture 'people' and 'that' as the above logic would not apply to these cases.

I am unable to take care of the words that do not have the keyword 'the' before and after (for example, 'that' and 'people' in the sentence).

```
p = re.compile(r'(?<=the\W)\w+') 
m = p.findall('the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks')

print(m)
```

The current output am getting is

```
'part','fair','most','fireworks'.
```

**Edit:**

Thank you for all the help below. Using the below suggestions in the comments, managed to update my code.

```
p = re.compile(r"\b(?!the)(\w+)(\W\w+\Wthe)?")
m = p.findall('the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks')
```

This brings me closer to the output I need to get.

Updated Output:

```
[('part', ' of the'), ('fair', ''),
 ('that', ' attracts the'), ('most', ''),
 ('people', ' is the'), ('fireworks', '')]
```

I just need the strings ('part','fair','that','most','people','fireworks').
Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally solved the question. Thank you all!

```
p = re.compile(r"\b(?!the)(\w+)(?:\W\w+\Wthe)?")
m = p.findall('the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks')
print(m)
```

Added a non-capturing group '?:' inside the third group.

Output:

```
['part', 'fair', 'that', 'most', 'people', 'fireworks']
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to look for words that do not immediately come before 'the' .

Note that the code below  does not use `re`.

```
words = 'the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks'
words_list = words.split()
words_not_before_the = []
for idx, w in enumerate(words_list):
    if idx < len(words_list)-1 and words_list[idx + 1] != 'the':
        words_not_before_the.append(w)
words_not_before_the.append(words_list[-1])
print(words_not_before_the)
```

output

```
['the', 'part', 'the', 'fair', 'that', 'the', 'most', 'people', 'the', 'fireworks']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to spin it around, instead of finding the words that does not immediately follow `the`, eliminate all the occurrences that immediately follow `the`

```
import re
test = "the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks"
pattern = r"\s\w*\sthe|the\s"
print(re.sub(pattern, "", test))
```

output: `part fair that most people fireworks`

Answer (score 0):

using regex:

```
import re
m = re.sub(r'\b(\w+)\b the', 'the', 'the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks')
print([word for word in m.split(' ') if not word.isspace() and word])
```

output:

```
['the', 'part', 'the', 'fair', 'that', 'the', 'most', 'people', 'the', 'fireworks']
```

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to look for words that do not immediately come before the.

Try this:

```py
import re

# The capture group (\w+) matches a word, that is followed by a word, followed by the word: "the"
p = re.compile(r'(\w+)\W\w+\Wthe')
m = p.findall('the part of the fair that attracts the most people is the fireworks')
print(m)
```

Output:

```py
['part', 'that', 'people']
```

Comment: Good question, I updated my answer to reflect what question of the OP I am trying to answer. I guess the ambiguity between the summary and the question details made me understand the problem only partially.